# C# operator 'is' arguments

Tags: c#, .net, types, operators

I am developing a small game for the fun of it and I stumbled upon a confusing moment with C#'s is operator. Here is the code:

```
public static InventorySlot FindSlotWithItem(this IInventory inventory, Type itemType)
{
    return inventory.InventorySlots.FirstOrDefault(t => t is itemType);
}
```

As it stands, this code doesn't compile as my Visual Studio tells me that type or namespace name 'itemType' could not be found. I was wondering why that is and looked for a bit of information on MSDN. And here is what I found:

> is (C# Reference):
>   Checks if an object is compatible with a given type. For example, the following code can determine if an object is an instance of the MyObject type, or a type that derives from MyObject

And these lines got me even more confused as I am clearly passing an object as the first parameter and the type as the second. I understand that this is connected to the fact that compiler looks for a type called 'itemType', but this is not exactly the behavior I want.

Please tell me why such syntax is not working and why 'itemType' is not considered a type by 'is' operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue here is that the objects of the `Type` class are not the same as the compile-time constant reference to a class. Instead, `Type` objects are just objects encapsulating the matadata of a class, and they thus can't be used to directly create variables, call static members, pass as generics, or be called with `is` the way an actual class reference can.

That being said, all the above operations have workarounds utilizing only the metadata. For type comparison, try

```
t => itemType.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetType());
```

This will check whether "a variable of type `itemType` can be assigned a value of type `t.GetType()`" - which will check not only for typing, but will also nicely accept polymorphic types without complaint.

Comment: That was what I actually wanted to know. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can do either this:

```
public static InventorySlot FindItem<T>(this IInventory inventory)
{
    return inventory.InventorySlots.FirstOrDefault(t => t is T);
}
```

or this:

```
public static InventorySlot FindItem(this IInventory inventory, Type itemType)
{
    return inventory.InventorySlots.FirstOrDefault(t => itemType.IsAssignableFrom(t.GetType()));
}
```

Comment: but the second one is not the same as the first one as it is not going to work for subclasses of itemType.

Comment: Note that `GetType() == itemType` will directly compare type for equality, not for assignability/inheritance as the `is` operator does - see `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`

Answer (score 2):

You can't check a type of the object like this, you have to use the Type name for the operator:

```
// doesn't work
t is itemType

//working
t is String
```

So, as @AmirPopovich suggested, you can use the generic method, which helps you to provide the Type for you `is` operator:

```
public static InventorySlot FindItem<T>(this IInventory inventory)
{
    return inventory.InventorySlots.FirstOrDefault(t => t is T);
}
```